# How to change itunes app link country code?

Tags: ios, app-store, app-store-connect

My app store app link is https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/appname/appid?l=pl&ls=1&mt=8

How can i change the country code "us" so it will be listed on app store below a country code that i will choose?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to link to a specific country, you have to change the "us" country code to one from Apple's country codes list: https://help.apple.com/app-store-connect/#/dev997f9cf7c

Examples:

- https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/id0123456789 --> US
- https://itunes.apple.com/fr/app/id0123456789 --> France
- https://itunes.apple.com/de/app/id0123456789 --> Germany

**Edit after end of the App Store affiliate program:**

<s>Recommended (=best user experience):</s>

If you want to get a link that automatically "translates" into the user's language use the "geo" subdomain:

https://geo.itunes.apple.com/app/id0123456789 (You can actually leave the country code in the link, still gets changed to the right store)

Comment: But if someone search it in google it won't be my country code, it needs to be in app store under my country code.

Comment: You cannot change that. If you want your app only to be available in your country, you have to change the availability of your app in iTunes Connect.

Go to your app > App Store Information > Pricing and Availability > Availability and edit the territories there

Comment: There must be a way, i see apps that are in the app store with my country code, so changing it to only my country will make the code right?

Comment: If you could provide us with links/examples/screenshots, it's easier to follow. I'm still not quite sure what you want to achieve. Be also aware that there is lots of stuff happening in the browser/iTunes that might change your experience. Best practice is using the geo.itunes.apple.com link, so your users will always get "their" App Store front.

Comment: No, it need to be on app store page, below country code i want. If you search google with phrase "tesco ezakupy app store" it will show you a https://itunes.apple.com/pl/app/... link, so this is what i want, or does it work automatically?

Comment: That's Google. If I search with google.pl and a location in Poland, I get https://itunes.apple.com/pl/app/

Comment: But it is app store link, so it you you search from google.com, you get what county code?

Comment: As described above, you will always get the locale country code, which does not really matter as the App Store information seem to be only in Polish. Once the user clicks on "View in iTunes" they'll be in their locale store front anyway.

Comment: It matters for my boss, but luckily it looks like it will be automatically the right country code, can't check yet, app in review and there is only us link in panel for now.

Comment: @kelin Probably related to Apple discontinuing the App Store Affiliate program (https://appleinsider.com/articles/18/08/01/apple-to-remove-apps-from-itunes-affiliate-program-in-october)